# Azure website using Visual basic - Html page

Tags: vba, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have published a HTML page in azure using VB, But I would like to place my source code in cloud (azure), from there the launch has to take place instead of placing it in my local system.

Could some one help me on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web App build-in support classic ASP pages. I just created a simple asp page(home.asp) with following code.

```
<%@  language="VBScript" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Classic ASP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>VBScript Powered ASP page on Azure Web Apps </h1>
    <%  
      Dim dtmHour 
      dtmHour = Hour(Now()) 
      If dtmHour < 12 Then 
        strGreeting = "Good Morning!" 
      Else   
        strGreeting = "Hello!" 
      End If    
    %>

    <%= strGreeting %>
</body>
</html>
```

After copy it to wwwroot folder of Azure Web App, I can view this page using this URL http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/home.asp

[image]

> But I would like to place my source code in cloud (azure)

To publish your VB code and html pages, you just need to copy all your files to the wwwroot folder of your Azure Web App. The easier way to do it is using FTP. Steps below are for your reference.

Step 1. Get FTP URL and account name from properties overview page of Azure Web App.

[image]

Step 2. From your FTP client (Visual Studio, FileZilla, etc), use the connection information you gathered to connect to your app.

Step 3. Copy your files and their respective directory structure to the /site/wwwroot directory in Azure.